# spring boot - use https only if ssl.key-store file exists

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, https, keystore

I added these lines to application.properties:

```
server.ssl.key-store: keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password: 111111
server.ssl.keyStoreType: PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias: tomcat
```

How do I use HTTPS only if the server.ssl.key-store file exists? Otherwise, I want to use HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved a compareable problem by setting those properties programatically. This mean, you could check if the key-store file exists before you start your application with
`SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);`

Depending on whether the key-store exists or not you could build a new args-array, which includes the old args and your ssl setting.

Comment: When I debug the application, 'arg' is an empty array, I'd expect to to contain the settings from the application.properties file.

Comment: 'args' just contains the settings from commandline. If you don't use any, it's empty. The reading of the properties file is part of the start of spring boot which will be done by calling ```SpringApplication#run```.  Fill 'args' with your ssl settings would be the same as setting it by commandline.

Comment: so I can add settings to args and it will be added to the settings in the properties file?

Comment: Just to clarify: The settings in args don't result in any changes of your properties  file, but they are part of the configuration of spring boot! There are a lot of ways to configure spring boot. For further info read e.g.: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config